# Getting script's real absolute path in /bin/sh

Tags: shell-script, dash, bourne-shell

I'm looking for a way to get the real absolute path to the current `/bin/sh` script.  It should work for situations like this one:

```
/path/to/symlink/in/PATH/somescript

    -> ../../Package/current/bin/somescript.sh
```

...where `../../Package/current` is itself a symlink pointing to `v1.23`.

**Important assumptions:** we assume that `readlink` is available, but does not necessarily have the `-f` option.

Since the code of interest is contained in the script's file, this code can safely assume that all the symbolic links are legit, and ultimately point to the right place (otherwise code would not have been found by the shell and executed in the first place).  IOW, there's no need to worry about symlink cycles, broken symlinks, etc.

Below I give my best attempt, but it strikes me as a bit of overkill.  Is there a simpler way?

---

Here's my version:

```
path_to_script () {
  TARGET="$1"
  BASENAME="$(basename "$TARGET")"

  (
    cd -P "$(dirname "$TARGET")"
    if [ -h "$BASENAME" ]
    then
        path_to_script "$(readlink "$BASENAME")"
    else
        echo "$PWD/$BASENAME"
    fi
  )

}

PATH_TO_SCRIPT="$(path_to_script "$0")"
```

Basically, it recursively follows symbolic links, using `cd -P` to resolve symlinks in paths.

Comment: Does your `readlink` have the `-f` option?

Comment: @cjm: thanks for pointing this out; I'd meant to mention it, but somehow forgot to in the end.  I've fixed my post to rectify the omission.

Comment: Can you assume GNU make? It has an absolute path function. If you're targeting developer machines, it's highly likely to be available. If you're targeting embedded systems, forget about it.

Comment: @Gilles: I'm targeting "end-user *nix-based systems".  I.e., primarily Ubuntu and Darwin users.

Comment: Usually I say "you must install the `realpath` program if you don't already have one"

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not only shorter but also easier to read; YMMV.

```
path_to_script () {
    if ! [ -L "$1" ]; then
        echo "$1"
    else
        path_to_script "$(readlink "$1")"
    fi
}
```